# How to save data in swift when changing view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have my main view controller and I have my settings view controller. When I go into the settings and flip a switch and go back to the main, my settings view controller goes back to its default settings and same with the name. How can I make it so it will save the data while the app is open and not go back to its default values?

Thanks

Comment: Save your changes into `NSUserDefaults` from settings view controller and get values from it in your `viewWillAppear` method of main view controller and set values to your UI according to `NSUserDefaults` values.

Comment: Instead of user defaults, use delegate methods or array which you can use in the whole application. Use user defaults in case u need to retain the state of the button even when the user signs out or terminate the application

Comment: I would suggest using a delegate method to notify the main view controller of the changes in the settings view controller. Its a much cleaner implementation than using the viewWillAppear method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use delegates instead of checking the user defaults every time I leave the settings page.

```
protocol SettingsViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func settingsDidChange()
}
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: SettingsViewControllerDelegate?
    func someSettingChanged(){
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        //... get the new settings
        defaults.set(newSettingsValue, forKey: "settingsKey")
        defaults.synchronize()
        delegate?.settingsDidChange()
    }

}
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    func showSettingsVC(){
        let settingsViewController = //Initialization method
        settingsViewController.delegate = self
        self.show(settingsViewController, sender: self)
    }
}
extension MainViewController: SettingsViewControllerDelegate{
    func settingsDidChange() {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let settingsValue = defaults.value(forKey: "settingsKey"){
            //// do the appropriate changes
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store your button state in userdefault

here is the example for swift 3:

you can get button state in actioin for valuechanged then you can store that in

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "buttonState")
    let buttonState = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "buttonState")

    if buttonState == true {

    }

  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Answer (score 0):

1) When view will appear call for setting screen get your data from NSUserDefaults and then fill data to options.

2) When user changes something update your UserDefaults and dont forget to Synchronize it.